# Using scanner to input 2 different string arrays at one click

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

So I need to input 10 questions and answers separately like this:

Question: -user inputs
Answer:-user inputs
then he presses enter and it goes into 2 separate arrays and  the program repeats another question and answer to input. after all 10 are done, the system will display everything after

what i've managed to do is allow the program to input one question and one answer but it goes ahead and prints without the other 9.

i tried a `for(int j=0;j < q.length ;j++)` but it goes through all the questions first before the answers

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] q= new String [10];
        String[] a= new String [10];

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ca=new Scanner(System.in);


        int j=0;
        if( j<10)
        { 
            System.out.println("Question");

            q[j]=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Choice A");

            a[j]=sc.nextLine();
            j++;
        }

        System.out.println("Array elements are : ");
        for (int i=0;i<q.length;i++)
            System.out.println("<item>"+q[i]+"</item>");
        System.out.println("Array elements are : ");
        for (int i=0;i<q.length;i++)
            System.out.println("<item>"+a[i]+"</item>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because the code that asks a question and answer is not in any kind of loop.  I suggest that you read up on the different types of loop that Java has to offer, maybe [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Additionally, there is no reason to use two Scanners on System.in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `while` loop not a `if` statement

```
if( j<10)
```

should be

```
while( j<10)
```